# how do I flip bmp image vertically

Tags: c++, c, bmp

I was writing bmp image reader and worked successfully but its flipped vertically how can I flip it to its original position, as Microsoft described the image is top-down if the height is negative integer number, therefore how can I flip the image, can anyone help me.

```c
void DrawImage(int x, int y, DIB *dib_header) {
    // check whether the image width in bytes are a multiple of 4 bytes or not
    Width = dib_header->width;
    Height = dib_header->height;
    bpp = dib_header->bpp;                            // expressed in bits
    RowSize = Width * (bpp / 8);                // multiplying the width by byte per pixel to get the actual size need to store the pixel data

    if(RowSize % 4 != 0 && bpp == 24) {                          // check if the rowsize is not a multiple of 4 bytes.
        // if the row is not a multiple of 4 bytes.
        // then calculate the rowsize and round it up to a multiple of 4 bytes.
        // to calculate RowSize to a multple of 4 bytes we use the below formula
        // RowSize = floor(bpp * ImageWidth + 31 / 32) * 4
        // this fomula is from BMP file structure on wiki pedia
        // we will overwrite the RowSize variable instead of creating new one.
        // if RowSize was a multiple of 4 bytes it will keep the data. otherwise it will be changed here.        
        RowSize = (bpp * Width + 31) / 32;          // in the RowSize Variable only the integer part will be saved, the number after the point will be discarded.
        RowSize = RowSize * 4;                      // then the integer part will be multiplied by 4 to make to a multiple of 4 bytes.

        // that is all you need to make.
        printf("is not a multiple of 4 bytes");
    }

    // now we need to calculate the PixelArraySize in order to allocate memory for our image.
    // therefore we use the formula provided by the BMP File Structure.

    PixelArraySize = RowSize * absolute(Height);            // sometimes the image height might be expressed in negative number so we need to pass it through absolute value function.
                                                                // if the image height is negative then it means the image is stored in top-down format.
    

    // now do swap the colors because they are stored in the form of BGR, therefore we need to change it to RGB

    // Swapping color values to RGB from BGR
    if(isSwapped == 0) {
        for(int i = Height; i > 0; i--) {
            for(int j = 0; j < RowSize; j+=3) {
                tempColor = PixelData[(i*RowSize+j)];
                PixelData[(i*RowSize+j)] = PixelData[(i*RowSize+j) + 2];
                PixelData[(i*RowSize+j) + 2] = tempColor;
            }
        }
        isSwapped = 1;
    }

    if(Height > 0)
        flip_image_array(PixelData, Width, Height);


    for(int i = Height - i; i > 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Width; j++) {
            int kk = 3 * j;

            red = PixelData[i*RowSize+kk];
            green = PixelData[(i*RowSize+kk) + 1];
            blue = PixelData[(i*RowSize+kk) + 2];

            colorBMP = (int)(colorBMP << 8) | red;
            colorBMP = (int)(colorBMP << 8) | green;
            colorBMP = (int)(colorBMP << 8) | blue;
            PutPixel(j + x, i + y, colorBMP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about simply replacing `x` with `height-x`? If that does not help, please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you do and where your problem is.

Comment: You put the pixels on the screen in the opposite order?

Comment: @gerhardh okay let me try it

Comment: @user253751 I know why but its not working, I did that too

Comment: And please only use tag for the language you are acutally using.

Comment: @Gerhardh I included my code, if it helps

Comment: What is `flip_image_array`? All your variables are undefined also

Comment: @Alazar try `if(Height > 0)` -> `if(Height < 0)`, or call `flip_image_array` unconditionally or remove the call to `flip_image_array` alltogether.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think that doesn't make any change because the function ` flip_image_array(PixelData, Width, Height);` doesn't work

Comment: If that function does not work, how do you expect us to fix it while you are hiding it? Please read the link about MCVE again. C stand for "complete"

Comment: @Alazar maybe it does work, but not the way you think it does. Or maybe the fact it doesn't work is the actual problem here. But we can't tell much about code you don't show.

Comment: @Gerhardh I just posted a code snippet they are defined

Comment: the function flip_image_array is just an empty function, that is why I said it doesnt work

Comment: `Width` etc. are still not defined. Please post real code. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: @Alazar You probably just found out yourself where the problem is. `flip_image_array` should not be empty but it should _actually_ flip the image.

Comment: @Alazar big bug here: `for(int i = Height - i; i > 0; i--)`: Look closely at this declaration: `int i = Height - i;`: you're initializing `i` with itself...

Comment: @Jabberwocky ohh I didn't see that thanks friend, It worked, I don't know how I put it there, thanks a lot

Comment: @Alazar where is the part where you put the pixels on the screen in the opposite order?

Comment: @user253751 `PutPixel(j + x, i + y, colorBMP);` here, but it worked